# D3 Tree node on click

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I currently have a D3 Tree layout with nodes that can be added at runtime with text appended to each node.  Almost everything works fine except the `node.on(..)` functions like `node.on("mousedown" ....)`. The problem is that the node itself doesn't respond to a click, the appended text does. I.E. `node.on("mousedown",...)` is fired when the appended text is clicked on, not the actual node.  Any guidance would be much appreciated!  Code for the core function is below, which simply takes in a JSON-style object and a parent id and then inserts that JSON data into the tree as a child of the given parent:

```
function update(record_to_add, parent) {
    if (nodes.length >= 500) return clearInterval(timer);

    // Add a new node to a random parent.
    var n = {id: nodes.length, Username: record_to_add.Username},
            p = nodes[parent];
    if (p.children) p.children.push(n); else p.children = [n];
    nodes.push(n);

    // Recompute the layout and data join.
    node = node.data(tree.nodes(root), function(d) { return d.id; });
    link = link.data(tree.links(nodes), function(d) { return d.source.id + "-" + d.target.id; });

    // Add entering nodes in the parent’s old position.
    node.enter().append("circle", "g")
            .attr("class", "node")
            .attr("r", 10)
            .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.parent.px; })
            .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.parent.py; });

    // Add entering links in the parent’s old position.
    link.enter().insert("path", ".node")
            .attr("class", "link")
            .attr("d", function(d) {
                var o = {x: d.source.px, y: d.source.py};
                return diagonal({source: o, target: o});
            });
    node.enter().insert("text")
            .attr("x", function(d) { return (d.parent.px);})
            .attr("y", function(d) { return (d.parent.py);})
            .text(function(d) { return d.Username; });

    node.on("mousedown", function (d) {
        var g = d3.select(this); // The node
        // The class is used to remove the additional text later
        console.log("FOO");
    });

    node.on("mouseover", function (d) {
        var g = d3.select(this); // The node
        // The class is used to remove the additional text later
        var info = g.append('text')
                .classed('info', true)
                .attr('x', 20)
                .attr('y', 10)
                .text('More info');
    });

    // Transition nodes and links to their new positions.
    var t = svg.transition()
            .duration(duration);

    t.selectAll(".link")
            .attr("d", diagonal);

    t.selectAll(".node")
            .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.px = d.x; })
            .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.py = d.y; });

    t.selectAll("text")
            .style("fill-opacity", 1)
            .attr("x", function(d) { return d.px = d.x; })
            .attr("y", function(d) { return d.py = d.y; });
}
```

Comment: Simply switching the order in which I appended the node and the text seemed to fix the problem.  However, I would like a more elegant solution with an explanation so I'm keeping the question open.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To avoid text elements getting in the way of your event capturing you can try configuring your text elements to ignore pointer events:

```
svg text {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

You can do it directly with d3 as well:

```
textSelection
    .attr('pointer-events', 'none');
```

Comment: Beautiful, just what I was looking for!

Comment: @user3707153 Just a suggestion: if you decided to go with the CSS version, I would recommend to avoid using `svg text` selector in practice, because all text elements in your svg will lose the ability to be selected or clicked on. Use a more specific class only for those text elements you want to disable.